# Terraform: How to amend instead of create GCP subnet?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We have about 5000+ subnets  in various projects and a new requirement has come up to change the "log_config" of all the subnets to match INTERVAL_10_MIN to aggregate more logs.

I tried to use the following Terraform code:

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnet-with-logging" {
  name          = "my-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.2.0.0/16"
  region        = "us-central1"
  network       = google_compute_network.custom-test.id

  log_config {
    aggregation_interval = "INTERVAL_10_MIN"
    flow_sampling        = 0.5
    metadata             = "INCLUDE_ALL_METADATA"
  }
}
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
Error Creating Subnetwork Error 409: The resource xxxx  already exists
```

but I wanted to amend the existing subnetwork rather than create a new one.

How do I amend an existing subnetwork in GCP with Terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to [import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/index.html) the resource first if you want Terraform to be able to manage it.

Terraform is careful not to touch anything that it has not explicitly been told to manage and is tracked in its relevant state file. Normally this is just through Terraform creating it but you can also import existing resources so that things created out of band eg either manually by clicking in a GUI, by some other tool but it's not a good idea to import a resource managed by another Terraform state file as you open yourself to producing a diff if the configuration is different for each and they attempt to keep overwriting each other.

Resource imports can be done one at a time, eg with the [`google_compute_subnetwork`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_subnetwork#import) by running the following command:

```sh
terraform import google_compute_subnetwork.default projects/{{project}}/regions/{{region}}/subnetworks/{{name}}
```

If you have 5000+ subnets you want to manage then you need to either mass import them - you could write a script to generate and run the above command or use something like [`terraformer`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) to automatically import lots of resources from your GCP account.

However, I'd caution against doing that and instead think about how you'd want to manage these resources with Terraform over a longer period of time rather than this one off change. A general best practice with Terraform is to consider minimising blast radius by splitting up resources (and their state files) into logical sections that have no dependency on each other. For example, you may have networks etc that are purely for dev, test or production and you should separate based on those so that you can apply Terraform to these separately to check and observe your changes before you impact production.

If you just want to make a one off change then Terraform is maybe not the right tool for the job here as Terraform is much better suited for managing the entire life cycle of a resource from creation, through many updates over time and potentially to deletion.